# Retrieve Raspberry PI wireless network

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireless

I have a Raspberry PI connecting to my home network via one of my wireless access points. I have wpa_supplicant.conf set up to roam any of 4 APs within range.

Is there a terminal command I can run to find out which access point the PI is using? Not able to find this tidbit online for some reason. 'ifconfig wlan0' lists the IP address and tons of information but not the WAP name. I could log in to each WAP and list its wireless clients but this would be easier.

Running the latest Raspbian release.

Comment: Related: [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of commands that will give you the SSID:

1. iwgetid
2. iwconfig

You can find out more details including the options you can pass with the following commands:

- man iwgetid
- man iwconfig

This will display the man (aka manual) page for the respective command.